# Celery / Django - How to make existing function into a task and handle existing logging

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Here's my scenario.  I have some functions like these in my Django project:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('farm')

def _move_horse(horse_id, attachment=None):
    if attachment:
        logger.info(...)
        #other_stuff
    else:
        logger.info(...)
        other_func() # contains more logging

def move_horse_to_field(horse_id):
    _move_horse(horse_id)

def move_horse_to_field_w_attachment(horse_id, attachment):
    _move_horse(horse_id, attachment)
```

Then I want to make this one a background task:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def move_horse_to_field(self, horse_id):
    _move_horse(horse_id)
```

But how do I make the logging in the called functions work both when called from the background task and normally?

Comment: what logging configuration do you have in place at the moment? p;ease describe in more detail how it works/doesn't work

Comment: It set's to write to a specified file, and email for error level log messages.

Comment: please answer my question in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tooling around for a while and trying different things, it seems to be as simple as setting this option:

CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False

Once I did that the celery workers seem to respect all of my existing log settings.  They write to the same file the Django app does, and they even send out emails when I log an error level message (a log setting I have)  In my case this was exactly what I wanted.

And I didn't seem to have to bother with the get_task_logger(**name**) at all.